# "Hard" areas in the cloth simulations (blender 4.1.0)

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm trying to model a jacket with stand-up collar. I'm using simply cloth pro add-on. Is there a way to implement this through this add-on? And if not, how can I do it without an add-on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing check the name of the pin group in the *Physics panel > Cloth >Shape > Pin Group*. This vertex group won't be affected by the cloth simulation:

[image]

Then select the collar vertex group and assign it to the pin group, the higher the *Weight* will be, the stiffer the collar will be:

[image]

Comment: I suppose then this group won't move at all? I've seen this method used to model fabrics "hung" on hooks. I just need this group to be minimally deformable, but still move along with the rest of the clothes.

Comment: It will move wth the charcter if your cloth is parented to the armature, and it will be as stiff as the weight will be high

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I will try it, TY.